# PHP Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting `Class 'Splash\\SiteBundle\\Util\\Resize' not found` when running my app on prod. This does not happen on dev.

Here is the code from the error:

```
$resize = new \Splash\SiteBundle\Util\Resize($this->getAbsolutePath());
```

I have a file called `Splash\SiteBundle\Util\Resize.php` with this namespace

```
namespace Splash\SiteBundle\Util;

Class Resize{  ... }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are you loading the classes?

Comment: @Lion A variable assignment.

Comment: I am using Symfony2. I believe there is an autoloader setup. When creating new Entities I simply create the class and then call `new Splash\SiteBundle\Entity\Entitiy()` and the class is auto loaded

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop You should tag symfony2 questions with `symfony2`, not `php`.

Comment: Gotcha, I noticed you added that tag, thanks

Comment: Where is the code that caused the error? Is it in Class Resize? You need to make that clear.

Comment: I hope the ``Resize.php`` file lives in `src/Splash/SiteBundle/Util/Resize`?

Comment: Can you show us the full error message ?

Comment: @Wouter Yes that is where the file lives. @Sybio here is the full error: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Splash\\SiteBundle\\Util\\Resize' not found in /home/splash/www/splash/src/Splash/SiteBundle/Entity/Asset.php on line 214` line 214 is shown above in original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love when its the little things. My `util` folder was not capitalized. I changed this and it works now. I'm surprised my dev machine did not fail w this error.

Answer (score 0):

So the quick fix is to add this `include dirname(__FILE__) . "/../Util/Resize.php"`
I am not sure why my production machine would need the include while my dev machine works fine without it. Using Symfony2 and the autoloader I have never needed to `include` a file. Not sure whats goin on but this get me past it for now

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible thing that could lead this to happen could ne not cleared cache

```
 php app/console cache:clear -e prod
```

Another stupid thought could be that production has merge conflicts within that file and PHP doesn't see the class compiled.